# unable to install a package using pip

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, fuse

I'm triying to install a package using pip inside a virtualenv:

`pip install fuse-python`

but  the output is

```
Downloading/unpacking fuse-python
  Downloading fuse-python-0.2.tar.gz (53kB): 53kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/home/nicu/dev/bacula/ve/build/fuse-python/setup.py) egg_info for package fuse-python
    Usage: pkg-config [-?] [--version] [--modversion]
            [--atleast-pkgconfig-version=VERSION] [--libs] [--static]
            [--short-errors] [--libs-only-l] [--libs-only-other] [--libs-only-L]
            [--cflags] [--cflags-only-I] [--cflags-only-other] [--variable=NAME]
            [--define-variable=NAME=VALUE] [--exists] [--print-variables]
            [--uninstalled] [--atleast-version=VERSION] [--exact-version=VERSION]
            [--max-version=VERSION] [--list-all] [--debug] [--print-errors]
            [--silence-errors] [--errors-to-stdout] [--print-provides]
            [--print-requires] [--print-requires-private] [-?|--help] [--usage]
    pkg-config could not find fuse:
    you might need to adjust PKG_CONFIG_PATH or your
    FUSE installation is very old (older than 2.1-pre1)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/home/nicu/dev/bacula/ve/build/fuse-python/setup.py", line 69, in <module>
        iflags = [x[2:] for x in cflags.split() if x[0:2] == '-I']
    NameError: name 'cflags' is not defined
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Usage: pkg-config [-?] [--version] [--modversion]

        [--atleast-pkgconfig-version=VERSION] [--libs] [--static]

        [--short-errors] [--libs-only-l] [--libs-only-other] [--libs-only-L]

        [--cflags] [--cflags-only-I] [--cflags-only-other] [--variable=NAME]

        [--define-variable=NAME=VALUE] [--exists] [--print-variables]

        [--uninstalled] [--atleast-version=VERSION] [--exact-version=VERSION]

        [--max-version=VERSION] [--list-all] [--debug] [--print-errors]

        [--silence-errors] [--errors-to-stdout] [--print-provides]

        [--print-requires] [--print-requires-private] [-?|--help] [--usage]

pkg-config could not find fuse:

you might need to adjust PKG_CONFIG_PATH or your

FUSE installation is very old (older than 2.1-pre1)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/home/nicu/dev/bacula/ve/build/fuse-python/setup.py", line 69, in <module>

    iflags = [x[2:] for x in cflags.split() if x[0:2] == '-I']

NameError: name 'cflags' is not defined

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/nicu/dev/bacula/ve/build/fuse-python
Storing debug log for failure in /home/nicu/.pip/pip.log
```

as far as i can tell there's something wrong with pkg-config and PKG_CONFIG_PATH

I'm running ubuntu 14.04, 
and the output of `dpkg -l | grep is` (so my fuse installation is not 'too old '):

```
ii  fuse                                        2.9.2-4ubuntu4                                      amd64        Filesystem in Userspace
ii  gvfs-fuse                                   1.20.1-1ubuntu1                                     amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - fuse server
ii  ifuse                                       1.1.2-0.1                                           amd64        FUSE module for iPhone and iPod Touch devices
ii  libfuse2:amd64                              2.9.2-4ubuntu4                                      amd64        Filesystem in Userspace (library)
```

UPDATE:
i installed it using sudo apt-get install python-fuse but that installed it globally:

```
ii  python-fuse       2:0.2.1-9   amd64    Python bindings for FUSE (Filesystems in USErland)
```

Comment: Working on Ubuntu 14.04, my installation went well. I tried both, from PyPi, or from downloaded tar.gz. In past, I was experimenting with FUSE and it might be, that I have in system installed some package, which are required.

Comment: You could try (long shot) `apt-get build-dep python-fuse` before you install.

Comment: i switched to fusepy which seems to work fairy well; pip install went smoothly

Answer (score 7):

Install `sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev` and retry. It works.